# Creating an object with more than 1 foreign key in a Django project with multiple databases causing error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

In my Django project, I have 2 databases. Everything works perfectly except for when I try to create a model with 2 foreign keys. The database router locks up and gives me a `Cannot assign "<FKObject: fk_object2>": the current database router prevents this relation.` even if both foreign keys come from the same database and I've yet to save the object in question. Code below

```
1 fk_object1 = FKObject.objects.using("database2").get(pk=1)
2 fk_object2 = FKObject.objects.using("database2").get(pk=2)
3
4 object = Object()
5 object.fk_object1 = fk_object1
6 object.fk_object2 2 = fk_object2
7 object.save(using="database2")
```

The problem arises on line 6, before the object is even saved into the database so I'm assuming that Django somehow calls `Object()` with `database1` even though it hasn't been specified yet.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Have you defined a custom database router?

Comment: I think the custom database router you have defined is having restriction of data modification

Comment: I have. I've tried altering behavior there but I haven't had any luck doing so.

When setting both fk_objects, `db_for_write` gets called however there seems to be no way to pass data to it. Even the instance that gets passed off as a hint comes up of type `str` instead of the actual instance that's getting passed off (in this case, `fk_bject1` or `fk_object2`)

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up finding a work around as such:

As it turns out, my suspicions were only partially true. Calling `Model()` does not cause Django to assume it is to use the default database but setting a foreign key does. This would explain why my code would error out at line 6 and not at line 5 as by this point in time, Django already assumes that you're using the default database and as `fk_object2` is called from `database2`, it errors out for fear of causing an inter-database relation.

To get around this, I used `threading.current_thread()` as so:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    current_thread().db_name = "database2"

    def handle(self, **args, **kwargs):
        # Do work here


class DatabaseRouter(object):
    db_thread = threading.current_thread()

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        try:
            print("Using {}".format(db_thread.db_name))
            return db_thread.db_name
        except AttributeError:
            return "default"

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        try:
            print("Using {}".format(db_thread.db_name))
            return db_thread.db_name
        except AttributeError:
            return "default"
```

This way, my 2nd database is used every time, thereby avoiding any possible relation inconsistencies.